# Getting error: TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'n' when printing report?

Tags: python, templates, odoo

I am trying to print a report for a custom module I am building with `Odoo`, but when I try to print I get the following error:

```
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/report.py", line 93, in go
    result, format = openerp.report.render_report(cr, uid, ids, object, datas, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/report/__init__.py", line 40, in render_report
    return registry['ir.actions.report.xml'].render_report(cr, uid, ids, name, data, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 155, in render_report
    return new_report.create(cr, uid, res_ids, data, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py", line 376, in create
    result = self.create_source_pdf(cursor, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 461, in create_source_pdf
    return self.create_single_pdf(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py", line 334, in create_single_pdf
    head_mako_tpl = mako_template(header)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py", line 88, in mako_template
    return mako_template_env.from_string(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 769, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 493, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source)
  File "<unknown>", line 24, in template
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'n'
```

I googled a lot and couldn't find any clue as to how to solve that issue.

I am using `webkit` reporting. Here is my `.mako` file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
   <body>
Testing
</body>
</html>
```

This is how I call the report from the `.py` file

```
report_sxw.report_sxw('report.hotel.webkit',
                      'hotel.webkit',
                      'addons/hotel_webkit/report/report_hotel.mako',
                      parser=report_webkit_html)
```

And finally the `XML` call

```
    <report id="sim.report_sim_hotel"
        name="hotel.webkit"
        auto="False"
        model="sim.resumen_wizard" 
        file="hotel_webkit/report/report_hotel.mako" 
        string="Hotel Report Test" 
        webkit_header="base_headers_webkit.base_reports_portrait_header"
        report_type="webkit"/>
```

Any clue as to what does that error means and what else can I test to make the report work will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find out what this was?

Comment: Hello @DannyW.Adair I ended up switching report types since webkit is depreciated. A pain at first but there was no point on keep fixing webkit errors as it is not used anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I did find the fix and will post as answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed this issue for our invoices.

Odoo switched from Mako in v7 to Jinja2 in v8, with a "simulated" Mako notation where *most* things work as before. Inline Python code doesn't, this "n" filter doesn't.

You have to switch from Mako's "|n" to Jinja2's "|safe" (this filter means "don't escape" - usually applied to things that return HTML).

- http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html
- http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping

If you are not using it in your template, it is probably in your base header!

We had a line

```
${_debug or ''|n}
```

in there which should read

```
${_debug or ''|safe}
```

for Odoo.